# Making sense of a sentence in a politcal economy article

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, meaning

Reading [this critical geopolitical economic article](http://www.globalresearch.ca/financial-warfare-geopolitics-and-macro-economic-agendas-what-happens-behind-the-scenes/5433067), I found myself troubled understanding this sentence:

"Markets have priced in nothing bad from here to as far as the eye can see."

Here's the greater context:

> Here is how I see all of this, the pot is boiling and the warring
>   factions are making stands, everywhere.  When I say “warring
>   factions”, I am talking about everything from hawks and doves in the
>   military and in the financial markets to as grand as the East versus
>   the West.  So many people have been conditioned that the can will
>   always get kicked down the road and nothing bad will ever be allowed
>   to happen.  I disagree.  There are just too many flash points in
>   multiple areas for this to continue.  **Markets have priced in nothing
>   bad from here to as far as the eye can see.**  Compensation for “risk”
>   does not exist anywhere.

I'm not sure whether "price in" is used as a phrasal verb -- as meaning the opposite of ["priced out"](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/priced-out.asp) -- or what. The rest of the sentence is also hard to make sense, maybe because I can't relate it to the context. Helps appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *price in* is a common idiomatic expression used in economics and finance  to express the concept that something ( an event, a change, news etc.) is  reflected in the price of an asset.

*Markets have not priced in nothing bad from here* means that financial markets have not changed ( in this case decreased) the price of the assets concerned reflecting  the bad news. ( probably implying that the news are not considered to have negative financial effects).

[Factor in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/factor-in): ( is a synonym expression)

> - to include a particular amount or factor when you calculate something
>   Total spending was virtually the same in real terms after factoring in inflation.

With that respect, *price in* is not the opposite of *priced out* which refers the the fact that an asset has a price out of line with the market price.